# Capturing windows keyboard strokes while script isn't current used process

Tags: python

I am trying to make an application that redoes my exact movements on keyboard on a certain process, so I am attempting to register my keyboard strokes time-stamped, I tried to do it using msvcrt or pygame, however they both require keys to be entered to the command prompt itself, else it wont detect it.

Is it possible to create a time-stamped "keylogger" using PYTHON
P.S: I just want to learn more about python scripting.

this is the code i tried:

```
import msvcrt
import time
import datetime
while True:
    char = msvcrt.getch()
    print char
    print datetime.datetime.now().time()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've written is a program that captures inputs to itself.  What you need, at least for Windows, are global input hooks.  This will allow your application to capture *all* input to the machine.

Take a look at the following resources:

[Windows Hooks Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Python for Windows Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)

[PyHook, a Python wrapper for global input hooks](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/?source=dlp)